# $\pi_0(X) \cong [*,X]$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $\pi_0(X)$ denote the set of path components of a space X.

I want to show that $\pi_0(X)$ is the set of homotopy classes of maps from the one point space ∗ to X, by constructing a bijection

$\pi_0(X) \cong [*,X]$

but I am unsure of where to start. Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Given a homotopy $H\colon I\times *\to X$, $H(*,t)\in X$, can you find a path in $X$?